# commons-text 1.11.0 with commons-lang3 3.13.0 still gives error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, apache-commons-lang3, apache-commons-text

When I use commons-text 1.11.0 with the upgraded commons-lang3 3.14.0,

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils
```

When I use commons-text 1.11.0, despite the maven repo states it depends on commons-lang3 3.13.0, I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.commons.lang3.Range org.apache.commons.lang3.Range.of(java.lang.Comparable, java.lang.Comparable)'
```

It only works when I use commons-text 1.10.0 with commons-lang3 3.12.0

Can anyone tell ne why it is so?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and post the entire stack trace of the `NoClassDefFoundError` when you use [commons] text 1.11 with commons-lang3 3.14 ?

Comment: I am also facing this problem, I use dropwizard framewok, and after update to 4.0.6 it started this error in exec. time no in compilation time. Maven load that dependency but doesent throw error.